# changing format of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

saying we have a data frame looking like this :
with x,y,z the value we are interested in.

```
        Year1  year2    year3
canada.   x1    x2       x3
```

[shape we have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20eFO.png)

can we transform it to a data frame 2 looking like the following :

```
Country  Year  Value
Canada   Year1  x1
Canada   Year2  x2
Canada   Year3  x3
```

[shape wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thEyg.png)

and so on for the other countries.
Is there a way to code this transformation ?

[Original data look like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VN4z7.png)

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way to do it

Assuming, in your given DF, country is an index field

```
# stack and reindex, then rename the columns
df.stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0': 'Country', 'level_1': 'Year', 0:'Value'})
```

```
Country     Year    Value
0   canada.     Year1   x1
1   canada.     year2   x2
2   canada.     year3   x3
```

if country is not an index then and is instead a column then

```
df.set_index('country').stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0': 'Country', 'level_1': 'Year', 0:'Value'})
```

Comment: accepting/upvoting is stackoverflow synonym for Thanks

Comment: when I use this line I lose the country names, any idea why?

Comment: Can you post the test data in the question?

Comment: yes , I just posed how the original data looks like

Comment: use the second solution, where you set index on 'countries', did you do that?

Comment: Yes @naveed I set the index and it worked perfectly. thanks a lot